# Dimension of an affine scheme, 24.5.7 of Vakil's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In the remark 24.5.7 of Vakil's book, it claims that the dimension of the scheme $\operatorname{Spec}k(x) \otimes k(y)$ is a $k(x)$-scheme with dimension one, where $k$ is a field and $x,y$ are two free variables while $k(x)$ and $k(y)$ are their rational fields.

I only know that $k(x) \otimes k(y)$ is a domain that is not a field, so the dimension of $\operatorname{Spec}k(x) \otimes k(y)$ is greater than $0$. But I do not know how to show the dimension is $1$!

Comment: Wait, why is $k(x)\otimes_k k(y)$ not equal to $k(x,y)$ ?

Comment: e.g. $x \otimes_k 1+ 1 \otimes_k y$ does not have a inverse from the construction of tensor product.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that we have $$k(x)\otimes_k k(y)\simeq S^{-1}k(y)[x],$$ where $S=k[x]\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: For a general result concerning the Krull dimension of a tensor product of two field extensions see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/82083/when-is-the-tensor-product-of-two-fields-a-field.

Comment: Thank you, I am being stupid.